# mySQL select the last message from each conversation

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, message

I have a user's table that stores all their sent/ received messages:

```
id | data_type | user_name | body | datetime
```

And what I want to achieve is:

1) To select the last row from each conversation, i.e the last inserted row of each unique user_name in the table that has a data_type of 1 (received message) or 2 (sent message).

2) Only get the rows that are older than a specific datetime, i.e WHERE datetime < from_datetime. (datetime is stored as UTC).

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? This is beyond my level of expertise.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id, body, user_name 
FROM user_harry
WHERE data_type = 1 OR data_type = 2
GROUP BY user_name
```

It returns the correct last id's of the rows, but the body's are not the ones from that row. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question is asked (and correctly answered) every . single . day in SO (and elsewhere) :-(

Comment: Yeah I saw many but I couldnt find one that used a single column for storing the recipient user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your existing query produces the correct ID values that you want then this should get you that and the body values associated with those rows:

```
select y.*
  from (select max(id) as max_id, user_name
          from user_harry
         where data_type in (1, 2)
         group by user_name) x
  join user_harry y
    on x.max_id = y.id
   and x.user_name = y.user_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope it works

```
SELECT user_harry.*
FROM user_harry INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) as max_id, user_name 
    FROM user_harry
    WHERE data_type IN(1,2)
    GROUP BY user_name
) temptable ON user_harry.id = temptable.max_id AND user_harry.user_name = temptable.user_name
```

Ahmet Vehbi Olgaç

Comment: That is literally the same exact query I posted except you called the sub "temptable" rather than "x"

Comment: If you can use `WHERE data_type BETWEEN 1 AND 2` then a compound index on `(data_type, user_name, id)` will make this inner query perform with excellence.